# JavaScript trouble with classList

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem to understand why my function doesn't work.

I have a FAQ page like this:

```
<div class="faq_box_after">
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to show the answer when I click on the .fa-plus, hide the answer when I click again on the plus, and hide answer when I click on another plus. I use this function in JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  let plus = document.querySelectorAll('.question_box_question .fas');

  for (let i = 0; i < plus.length; i++) {

    plus[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let answer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
      let totAnswer = document.querySelectorAll('.question_box_answer');
      for (let j = 0; j < totAnswer.length; j++) {
        if (totAnswer[j].classList.contains('active')) {
          totAnswer[j].classList.remove('active');
        }

      }
      answer.classList.toggle('active');

    }, false)

  }
});
```

So if I delete the for cycle, that remove all the active class, the toggle work but if I use the for cycle, the toggle work only to show, not to hide.

Comment: Would you explain a little bit more about what you want to do? Especially the roles of those elements and event listeners?

Comment: Try adding the condition `totAnswer[j] !== answer` to your `if` statement, i.e. `if (totAnswer[j] !== answer && totAnswer[j].classList.contains('active')){ ...`

Comment: Note that the `if contains { remove } else { add }` can be replaced with `answer.classList.toggle('active');`

Comment: @PanwenWang i have a faq page, with a question and a button. i wanto to show the answer when i click the button, and hide when i click again. but i want that if i click on a button of other question, the eventlistener close all the shows answer. sorry for my english, i'm trying to do my best XD

Comment: @Lennholm thank you man this working!

Comment: @Dario I wrote it as an answer just now, please accept it to mark this question as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work to close the opened answer because when you loop through all the answers, this includes the answer you want to close. Consequentially, the `active` class gets removed from that answer in the loop and then it gets added again when you run `answer.classList.toggle('active')`

The solution is to simply not remove the `active` class on that answer in the loop which you can accomplish by including a condition for it in your `if` statement, like this:

```
      ...
      for (let j = 0; j < totAnswer.length; j++) {
        if (totAnswer[j] !== answer && totAnswer[j].classList.contains('active')) {
          totAnswer[j].classList.remove('active');
        }

      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to iterate over all of the answers except the one associated with the plus you clicked and hide those. Then toggle the one you clicked.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.question_box').forEach(el => {
  el.querySelector('.fa-plus').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const answer = e.target.closest('.question_box').querySelector('.question_box_answer');
    document.querySelectorAll('.faq_box_after .question_box_answer').forEach(ans => ans != answer && ans.classList.remove('show'));
    answer.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.question_box_answer { display: none; }
.question_box_answer.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="faq_box_after">
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question">q<i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer">a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question">q<i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer">a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question">q<i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer">a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question">q<i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer">a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question">q<i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer">a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question_box">
        <p class="question_box_question">q<i class="fas fa-plus">+</i></p>
        <p class="question_box_answer">a</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the check to skip current (clicked) element

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  let plus = document.querySelectorAll('.question_box_question .fas');

  for (let i = 0; i < plus.length; i++) {

    plus[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let answer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
      let totAnswer = document.querySelectorAll('.question_box_answer');
      for (let j = 0; j < totAnswer.length; j++) {
        // just skip the clicked element
        if(answer === totAnswer[j]) continue;
        if (totAnswer[j].classList.contains('active')) {
          totAnswer[j].classList.remove('active');
        }

      }
      answer.classList.toggle('active');

    }, false)

  }
});
```